# Magento 1.9 How to call any api on event "sales_order_invoice_register"?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, sales-order, invoice

I want to call my custom API on **sales_order_invoice_register** event. Menas, when the invoice will generate, will call **my custom API** and I want to store the response in **Database**.

**Will this kind of functionality feasible for this event?**

**Also, can I use curl call here? or any other method?**

Can anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your your extension `config.xml` add code like this:

```
<global>
    <events>
      <sales_order_invoice_save_after><!--<sales_order_invoice_register>-->
        <observers>
          <your_module> <!-- any unique identifier -->
            <class>your/observer</class>
            <method>yourObserverMethod</method>
          </your_module>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_invoice_save_after><!--<sales_order_invoice_register>-->
    </events>
  </global>
```

And in observer you can get invoice data like this :

```
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
$invoice_id = $invoice->getData('entity_id');
```

Now create the Observer file with path which you given above.
And added function like you can added define above.

Yes you can do any code here, what ever you want.

Comment: Thanks, @Dhiren Vasoya. Can I get an Invoice Id here in the observer? if yes then how? Can I use "sales_order_invoice_save_after" event in Magento 1.9.3.4?

Comment: Same way you can create another event for "sales_order_invoice_save_after"

Comment: I update answer please check, if useful then upvote and accept it, so it will helpful to other into community.

Comment: Thanks, @Dhiren Vasoya. Will $invoice_id = $invoice->getData('entity_id'); is the latest generated id? And how to check if this observer called once when an invoice is created, not on invoice update? is there any default function to check it?

Comment: hello, Dhiren I used "sales_order_invoice_register" event but I didn't get the invoice_id there.. any other way we can get the invoice id?

Comment: @UtsavGupta post the new question with your code what you have done, so you get the information about that.

Comment: It is working fine with the "sales_order_invoice_save_after" event. otherwise, your answer is correct.. please update the event in your answer